# Django - can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes or no result appears

Tags: python, django

I got a model / view for Story project. My goal is to give only a time to stories to appear on my website.

```
class Story(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='story/')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
        
    def save(self):
        super().save()
            
    @property
    def is_active(self):
        #now = timezone.now()
        if (self.created_on + timedelta(days=10)) > datetime.now():
            return False
        return True 

@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/cooker/login'),name="dispatch")       
class StoryList(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Story.objects.order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'user_list_story.html'
    model = Story
```

I get this issue:
**can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes** So I've tried to correct it in order to the same comparaison.

```
@property
    def is_active(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        if (self.created_on + timedelta(days=10)) > now:
            return False
        return True
```

But nothing appears on my page. Here is the code template.

```
{% for story in story_list %}
      {% if story.is_active %}
      
      
      {{ story.title }}
      
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Did you set `USE_TZ = True` in the `settings.py`?

Comment: Yes and I added from django.utils import timezone in my models

Comment: what is value of created_on in your table, also why don't you use filter on queryset instead

Comment: I've tried to use Filter on queryset but I got an issue. I got (created_on): 2020-09-11 17:15:42.725268

Comment: 2020-09-11 17:15:42.725268 + 10 days is more than now()

Comment: @Louis: you probably want to swap `True` and `False`, so `return self.created_on + timedelta(days=10) > now`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to perform this validation, you can *filter* the queryset. This is more efficient since the filtering is done at the *database* side:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.utils.timezone import now

class StoryList(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    queryset = Story.objects.order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'user_list_story.html'
    model = Story
    login_url = '/cooker/login'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            created_on__gte=now()-timedelta(days=10)
        )
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).